# Alexa skill not responding, when connected to MongoDB using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, alexa-skills-kit

Alexa skill using node.js, returns no value when mongoose.connect is called.

```
const Alexa = require('ask-sdk-core');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const LaunchRequestHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'LaunchRequest';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const speakOutput = 'Welcome, to skill or ask for Help. Which would you like to try?';
        var options = {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true
        };

         const connectDb = async () => {
              await mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv:uri', options).then(
              () => {
                  console.log("connected to database");
                  return handlerInput.responseBuilder
                    .speak(speakOutput)
                    .reprompt(speakOutput)
                    .getResponse();
              },
              err => { console.log(err) })
          }
         connectDb().catch(error => console.error(error))
    }
};

exports.handler = Alexa.SkillBuilders.custom()
    .addRequestHandlers(
        LaunchRequestHandler,
    )
    .addErrorHandlers(
        ErrorHandler,
    )
    .lambda();
```

Console looks like below

```
    05:52:07
    2020-05-06T05:52:07.07 INFO connected to database

    05:53:12
    REPORT Duration: 67067.17 ms Billed Duration: 67000 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 100 
    MB Init Duration: 512.31 ms

    05:53:12
    2020-05-06T05:53:12.858 Task timed out after 67.07 seconds
```

I have tried increasing the timeout bar but that's not the issue which might be causing problem here, when *mongoose.connect()* is added, skill does not return anything from that moment.
My aim here is to establish connection with mongo Db atlas and notify alexa user, if connection is successful.